# Can't connect to mysql database any way I try

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to connect to a mysql database many different ways but no matter how I do it I get an error. I'm pretty new to php so it might be my mistake but I would appreciate any help.

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "xyz";
    $password = "1234567";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

All of the information is correct but it returns Connection failed: Access denied for user 'xyz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: make sure the connection was successful... add a die() function to mysql_connect then try again

Comment: you shouldn't use that deprecated API in the first place, why not use `mysqli_*` instead. its got the procedural interface too, not much different in mysql function. plus you get to use prepared statements, which will make your queries safer.

Comment: I'm very new to MySQL and PHP so I'm trying out different connection scripts I see online. I'm going to edit my question with the newest one I've tried from w3schools

Comment: .. have you verified that the username/password actually works for that host through something other than PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqli_connect($serverName,$Username,$Password,$Database);
```

Try appending your database name to the final parameter

---

Solutions:

1. Have you granted your user access to the database schema?
2. Have you ensured you're using the correct password/user?
3. Have you ensured your server name is correct? (Not localhost,
   possibly an external IP?)

A possible solution would be try the server IP, as DNS can sometimes fail. Incase you was unaware, localhost IP is `127.0.0.1`

Comment: I've tried it still gives me the same error. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in cpanel but I created it with those exact parameters

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Out of my own stupidity I forgot cpanel put a prefix before my username so I had to enter that.

Answer (score 0):

Put localhost into quotes:

```
mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);
```

The error message `Access denied for user 'xyz'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` is an indication that either the password is wrong or the user xyz has not been installed as descibed in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html

Answer (score 0):

The username and password you specified is not registered as a database administrator.... the default username is root and password is blank

Answer (score 0):

basically you did not set up permission correctly, double check host.

run

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
```

to check what is host address you provided